# How to prevent outstanding jquery ajax events throwing error when new page is loaded in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, xmlhttprequest

If I have outstanding jQuery $.ajax events that are awaiting a response from the server, they all throw errors when a new page is loaded (by a user clicking on an href for example). This seems to be a new behavior in Firefox 8 and above.

Strangely JavaScript for the current page seems to continue to run while the new page is loaded. So when the error is triggered, I'd like to detect that it's a special case, an "abort because new page was loaded while awaiting an Ajax reponse" type error and swallow it.

The problem is that none of the properties returned through the ajax error event jqXHR or textStatus, errorThrown return any information besides "error".

So how do I detect this specific error type? or how do I detect the Firefox has begun loading a new page, so I can ignore the error?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [jQuery unload method](http://api.jquery.com/unload/) for this:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
   // setIgnoreErrorFlag / cancel outstanding requests etc
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like the order of operations in Firefox is to abort all outstanding ajax events (triggering an error in $.ajax), and only afterwards is the $(window).unload() event triggered.